# Dynamic URL in DRF Modelviewset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I'm working on a url where I'm filtering the News according to category. So all i am doing is passing the name of the category in url in this manner `127.0.0.1:8000/news/category/sports/` or `127.0.0.1:8000/news/category/entertainment/`. Here's my code snippet

`views.py`

```
class CategoryAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    # lookup_field = 'slug'
    # permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = Category.objects.all()
        return category

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_path=r'list/(?P<name>[\w-]+', url_name='category')
    def get_category(self, request, category=None):
        return Category.objects.all().order_by(name)

class PostAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    # permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]

    def get_queryset(self):
        news_post = News.objects.all()
        return news_post
```

`serializers.py`

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    dislikes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    views = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    # author = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    # category = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    def get_likes(self, obj):
        return obj.likes.count()

    def get_dislikes(self, obj):
        return obj.dislikes.count()

    def get_views(self, obj):
        return obj.views.count()
        
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('id','category','post_type','title','content','hash_tags','source','author','views',
                  'likes','dislikes','status')


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = PostSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    parent = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name', 'slug', 'parent','posts']
```

`urls.py`

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('news', views.PostAPI, basename='news'),
router.register('category', views.CategoryAPI, basename='category'),
router.register('news-images', views.NewsImageAPI, basename='news-image'),
router.register('comment-room', views.CommentRoomAPI, basename='comment-room'),
router.register('comment', views.CommentAPI, basename='comment')

urlpatterns = [
        
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

So all I want to do is instead of passing the name of the category in the url, how can I create it dynamically. Otherwise I need to create a url for each category.
For eg: `127.0.0.1:8000/news/category/health/`,`127.0.0.1:8000/news/category/business/`
So how can I avoid it. I need a help from you guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just crete an end point like

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def list_post_of_category(request,name=None):
    category = Category.objects.get(name=name)
    posts = category.posts.all().filter(is_active=True)
    serializer = PostSerializer(posts,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

urlpatterns = [
path('post/category/<str:name>',list_post_of_category),
]
```